# Get a link informing on which application is launched

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the link by which my android application get launched.

I've created several links in which I'm passing a parameter as source that indicates which application gets open such as email, SMS or push notification.

Eg.

```
http://abc.example.com/app?source="email"
http://abc.example.com/app?source="pn"
```

But I'm not able to get that link within my application.

Answer (score 1):

getIntent().getAction() will give you the clue. Try this in your Launcher activity.

Comment: getIntent().getAction() returns intent filter action only which defined in AndroidManifest file.